# Nokogiri search over a document and modify parent node and can't access child node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using nokogiri to search through an HTML document using the `css` method. When I find an element I modify it by wrapping it in another element and reinserting it into that node. The issue is if that element that contains a child with a class that I am searching for, since I modify the parent node it skips the child.

Here is an example to help explain.

```
html_string = <<-HEREDOC
  <div class="mt-1 parent-div">
    <div class="mt-1 child-div">Hello</div>
  </div>
HEREDOC

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_string)
doc.css('.mt-1').each do |node|
  node.replace(Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<div>#{node.to_html}</div>"
end
```

The `child-div` never gets accessed because the parent had it's contents rebuilt and it doesn't research the updated node.

Is there a way I can update the parent node and still have access to the child node on the next loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question with a bit of consulting from coworkers. The issue is that we are modifying from parent to child. What I really want to do is modify from child to parent so that I never mess with the contents of anything.

To do so I sort the node list in reverse order of the number of ancestors the element has.

```
# the key change -> .sort_by{ |n| n.ancestors.size }.reverse!    
doc.css('.mt-1').sort_by{ |n| n.ancestors.size }.reverse!.each do |node|
  node.replace(Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<div>#{node.to_html}</div>"
end
```

Comment: Looks as if your code got cut off: the `replace` and `parse` invocations don't have closing parentheses.